# what is the difference between pattern matching operators?

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, sh

i have some questions about pattern matching operators.

what's difference between these examples

```
$ VAR=/usr/bin/iecset
$ echo ${VAR#*/}
  usr/bin/iecset
```

and

```
$ VAR=/usr/bin/iecset
$ echo ${VAR##*/}
  iecset
```

and

```
$ VAR=/usr/bin/iecset
$ echo ${VAR%*/}
  /bin/iecset
```

and

```
$ VAR=/usr/bin/iecset
$ echo ${VAR%%*/}
```

Comment: Isn't the difference explained clearly in the Bash manual?

Comment: I could post an answer, but I'd basically just be quoting from the manual.

Comment: If you're not sure where it's documented, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: thanks @Barmar i didn't search in documents, i have watched the lesson and i didn't understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "pattern" here is a *glob* or *extended glob* pattern - most people call them wildcards.  The characters have a different meaning to those used in Regular Expressions.  So `*` means "zero or more of any character".

```
${var#pattern}    # delete shortest match of pattern from left
${var##pattern}   # delete longest match of pattern from left 
${var%pattern}    # delete shortest match of pattern from right 
${var%%pattern}   # delete longest match of pattern from right
```

Your examples:

(Bad idea to use uppercase variable names)

Hints:

1. to delete from the left, the `*` goes on the left.
2. `#` delete from left, as `#` is on the left in "We are #1"
3. `%` delete from the right, as the `%` is on the right in 50%

`var=/usr/bin/iecset`

Remove the shortest string on the left ending in /

```
echo ${var#*/}
usr/bin/iecset
```

There are no characters to the left of the first /, remember that `*` means *zero* or more.  So the leftmost / is removed.

Remove the longest string on the left ending in /

```
echo ${var##*/}
iecset
```

The next two are wrong in your post!  To delete from the right, the `*` should be on the right of the /.

```
$ echo ${VAR%*/}      # WRONG
$ echo ${VAR%%*/}     # WRONG
```

I think you mean:

Delete the shortest string on the right starting with /

```
var=/usr/bin/iecset
echo ${var%/*}
/usr/bin
```

Delete the longest string on the right starting with /

```
echo ${var%%/*}

(blank line)
```

There are many other meta-characters other than `*` you can use.